# Error in running applet in appletviewer: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, html, applet

I just ran into trouble in applet execution in webpage:
An error dialog popped up:
[image: "calculator is my class name and Exercise4 is the folder that contains it"]

calculator is my class name and Exercise4 is the folder that contains it. I am sure that the html file and the calculator.class are in the same folder named Exercise4. What is happening in here?

Answer (score 0):

> I am sure that the html file and the calculator.class are in the same folder named Exercise4.

That would be a problem.  The HTML needs to be at the root, not inside the 'package' directory.